# Rearrange rows of a given numpy 2D array given a list with the permutations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

There's an incredibly simple way of permuting the **columns** of a 2d array with numpy like this:

```
array1 = np.array([[11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
                  [66,  77,  88,  99, 100]])

print("Original array:")
print(array1)
permutation = [1,3,0,4,2]

result = array1[:, permutation]
print("New array:")
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
Original array:
[[ 11  22  33  44  55]
 [ 66  77  88  99 100]]
New array:
[[ 22  44  11  55  33]
 [ 77  99  66 100  88]]
```

[Visual representation (from w3resource.com)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOueN.png)

Is there a way to acomplish the same thing as elegantly but for the **rows** instead?

Comment: `result = array1[permutation]`?

Comment: Oh wow, thank you @Marat, I feel like I'm devolving

Answer (score 0):

As @Marat mentioned in the comments, you can do the same by similar advanced indexing that you described for columns:

```
array1 = np.array([[11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
                  [66,  77,  88,  99, 100]])
permutation = [1,0]
array1[permutation]
#[[ 66  77  88  99 100]
# [ 11  22  33  44  55]]
```

When you advance index numpy array, the default is calling rows.